Illegal access exception when using AMQP header in Mule 4 for JSON format
I'm trying to use a header from AMQP in my Mule flow inside a Transform Message component, but an IllegalAccessException is thrown ONLY if output is JSON (not Java).
What am I doing wrong?
<amqp:config name="AMQP_notifications_Config"
        doc:name="AMQP notifications Config"
        doc:id="4e026e79-f904-48b9-a49b-a0fc00035134">
    <amqp:connection host="${RABBITMQ_HOST}"
            port="${RABBITMQ_PORT}"
            virtualHost="notifications"
            username="${RABBITMQ_NOTIFICATIONS_USERNAME}"
            password="${RABBITMQ_NOTIFICATIONS_PASSWORD}" />
</amqp:config>
<flow name="mytestFlow"
        doc:id="26d25276-5c5c-413c-ad8e-7126d0041a1a">
    <amqp:listener doc:name="Listener"
            doc:id="153d3083-def0-4b28-bcd9-b3c4706f05da" config-ref="AMQP_notifications_Config" queueName="notifications"/>
    <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="31aa483f-9dc6-4584-b439-2f5bcb83f464">
        <ee:message>
            <ee:set-payload>
                <![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    "key": attributes.headers.myHeader
}]]>
            </ee:set-payload>
        </ee:message>
    </ee:transform>
</flow>

Error:
     Illegal access while trying to access field `stream` at class `com.rabbitmq.client.impl.LongStringHelper$ByteArrayLongString`. Please verify that the correct getter method is being defined.
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class org.mule.weave.v2.module.pojo.reader.PropertyDefinition (in module org.mule.weave.module.java) cannot access a member of class com.rabbitmq.client.impl.LongStringHelper$ByteArrayLongString with modifiers "public"
     jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.newIllegalAccessException(Reflection.java:392)
     java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:674)
     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:561)
     org.mule.weave.v2.module.pojo.reader.PropertyDefinition.read(PropertyDefinition.scala:153)
     org.mule.weave.v2.module.pojo.reader.JavaBeanPropertyValue.value(JavaBeanPropertyValue.scala:18)
    org.mule.weave.v2.model.values.wrappers.DelegateValue.evaluate(DelegateValue.scala:23)

JSON formatted message with header value

Version of the AMQP connector? Version of Mule 4? Is that the full error message? [edit] the question and add any lines before or after if any.
